# How to disable autoformatting in microsoft chat on sender's side? I type an underscore, teams turns it to italic

Tags: microsoft-teams, chat

In Microsoft Teams chat, if I type a second underscore character in a chat line, Teams tries to turn the part of the line between the two underscore characters to italic and removes the underscores.  I find this very annoying, because I do often want to type underscore characters.  In the rare case when I do want to type italic, I can press control-I to do just that.  Is there some way to disable this behavior?

The only workaround that I know is to copy-paste the text from elsewhere, but that's not a particularly nice way to use a real-time chat program.

Comment: I do not have teams to test it, nbut in most microsoft programs I workl around it by adding a space and then deleting that space. E.g dash dash space enter. Curtsor to space, delete, leaving to dashes instead of a reformat to a long line.  Or in this case underscore space I space underscore, cursor left, del, cursur left, backspace.

Comment: You're not alone https://microsoftteams.uservoice.com/forums/555103-public/suggestions/36501856-need-ability-to-enable-disable-auto-formatting-ma

Comment: This isn't a solution, but that behavior is because the text field is using markdown. In markdown, you put anything you want _italics_ between underscores, anything you **bold** between double asterisks and anything you want to be `code` between backticks.

Comment: @bobsfriend Markdown is somewhat less agressive in interpretting codes as formatting than the teams chat input. It only looks for start of italic at the start of a word and end of italic at the end of a word. Teams chat will make the middle of basic_string_view italic.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Z</kbd> after typing the second underscore character, and it should return to what you originally typed.